# How do I combine two columns, each containing numbers, into a date column?

Tags: excel

Here's my spreadsheet, in CSV form:

```
colA,colB,colC
10,11
1,12
```

colA has numbers representing the month, colB the year. I want this as the result:

```
colA,colB,colC
10,11,10-11
1,12,01-12
```

...where colC is formatted as a month-year date. I want colC to be formatted as a Date. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all years are above 2000, i.e. Column *B = 12* then year is *2012*

Try this:

```
=DATE(2000+B3,A3,1)
```

and format the cell as `mm-yy`

This results in a serial date

Answer (score 0):

In your colC, `=(A2&"-"&B2)`

If you need it to be 2 digits for each number

```
=(TEXT(A3,"00")&"-"&TEXT(B3, "00"))
```

Comment: That makes it look like `1-12`, but it doesn't act like a Date

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `DATE(year, month, day)` function. For example, `=DATE(B2, A2, 1)`. Note that the year needs to be full 4 digits (eg. 2011 rather than 11). 2 digits causes ambiguous meaning (ie. it can either start with 19 or 20).
2. Right click > Format Cells > Custom Date Time > yy-mm